# Finishing and relaunching activity to toggle dark mode seems to result in multiple instances of activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a button in a fragment that toggles a dark theme on some of the fragments in a main app Activity. When the toggle is tapped by the user, the following code is executed in the fragment:

```
if (isChecked) {
               Util.startNewThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       Utilities.saveUserNightModeStatus(true);
                   }
               });

                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                getActivity().finish();
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

There's also an `else` block with (essentially duplicate) code for switching the other way.

When the device on which the app is running is oriented opposite of the home screen orientation (so, for example, held in landscape orientation with a portrait homescreen) and in dark mode, and the home button is pressed to put the app in the background, and then the app is brought back to the foreground again, `onPause()` gets called after `onResume()`, and if the home button is pressed again, a crash occurs because of unregistration of some receivers in `onPause()` that had already been unregistered (because onPause had been called after onResume).

Another weird effect is that sometimes a dialog box doesn't appear when it's supposed to, but if dark mode is toggled off after the instigating action, the dialog box appears (i.e., something is tapped on, the dialog box doesn't appear, dark mode is then toggled off, and then the dialog box appears, without having to tap again on anything, as if it were there all along, but associated with an already running light mode activity).

**I observe that if the orientation is changed after resuming the app, everything is OK. This seems like a strong clue, but I'm not sure what it means or what to do with this knowledge.**

Switching the order of the calls to `finish()` and `startActivity()` did not help, nor did using an interface in the fragment to communicate back to the activity when it should finish itself. The problematic behavior always seems to appear in dark mode, which is not the default (i.e., when you first intall the app, it's in light mode).

I imagine that using some intent flag may fix this, but before doing a lot of experimentation and causing unintended consequences, since there seem to be many options with those flags, I'd like to see if someone here knows what's going on and can provide a good remedy.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `recreate()`?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `recreate()`. I'll try that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, same problem with `recreate()`. At least it's less verbose .

Comment: Have you tried waiting until your `saveUserNightModeStatus(true)` returns before recreating your activity? Otherwise it sounds like a race condition

Comment: It does look as if that code could create a race condition, or at least the wrong sequence of events. Let me investigate that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I still have the original problem (trying to recreate the activity in a callback from `saveUserNightModeStatus` didn't help). Is there a way that I can see if multiple instances of the activity are running?